# PGError: ERROR: operator does not exist: numeric = boolean

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Using hibernate 5.2 and postgreSQL 42.2 we are getting this error:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Operator
>   existiert nicht: numeric = boolean   Hinweis: Kein Operator stimmt mit
>   dem angegebenen Namen und den Argumenttypen überein. Sie müssen
>   möglicherweise ausdrückliche Typumwandlungen hinzufügen.   Position:
>   559   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:150)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:113)
>   ~[postgresql-42.2.4.jar:42.2.4]   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:353)
>   ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final-pit2.jar:5.3.4.Final]

Mapping looks like:

```
<id name="id" column="id"  type="long">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
</id>
<property name="abool" type="java.lang.Boolean" column="abool" />
```

Query looks like:

```
session.createQuery("from " + TestUser.class.getName() + " where
abool=true").list();
```

Comment: Have you tried `where abool is :mybool`? Postgres is kind of a stickler for using the `IS` syntax, where as MySQL will happily accept `=` instead, so that people don't have to rewrite their queries depending on the data.

Comment: We have to use several dbms like DB2, Oracle, MS-SQL-Server. The above query works for all of them. So a solution that does not require changes of individual queries is better in our case.

Comment: "abool is :myboolean" and
query.setBoolean( "myboolean", boolValue); works too!

Answer (score -1):

**Best Solution:**

use query parameters like

```
 query = session.createQuery("from " + TestUser.class.getName() + " where
abool=:myboolean");
  query.setBoolean( "myboolean", boolValue);
```

- better typ conversion for all databases
- sql-injection is not possible
- better performance because of preparedStatement caching

**Solution for huge codebase:**
Create your own dialect class:

```
public class PostgreSQL9DialectParcIT
    extends PostgreSQL9Dialect {

    public String toBooleanValueString(boolean bool) {

        return bool ? "1" : "0"; //$NON-NLS-1$//$NON-NLS-2$
    }
```